# CSS Position fixed parent pseudo element below

Tags: css

Here , in the example below ..the parent is FIXED ...the pseudo element lies on top of parent...

HTML

```
<div class="b"> </div>
```

CSS

```
 .b
{
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #a7a7a7;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  position: fixed;
}
.b::after
{
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border:1px solid #a7a7a7;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  z-index:-1;
  background: red;
}
```

http://codepen.io/annamalai-saro/pen/wBqzzX

I want it below the parent...??

Answer (score 0):

use this css instead of top:

```
.b::before
{
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
border:1px solid #a7a7a7;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  z-index:-1;
  background: red;}
```